# Angular content projection not working with storybook

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Using **Storybook 6.5.*** and **Angular 14**.

I have a **ButtonComponent** with the following content

*button.component.ts*

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent {

  @Input() color: 'primary'|'secondary'|'success'|'info'|'warning'|'danger' = 'primary';

  @Input() type: 'submit'|'button' = 'button';

  @Input() size: 'default'|'sm'|'lg' = 'default';

  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;

  @Input() outline: boolean; false;

  @Input() block: boolean = false;

  @Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }
}
```

*button.component.html*

```html
<button [type]="type"
        class="btn btn-{{ outline ? 'outline-' : ''}}{{color}} my-4 mb-2"
        [class.btn-sm]="size === 'sm'"
        [class.btn-lg]="size === 'lg'"
        [class.w-100]="block"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        (click)="onClick.emit()">
  <ng-content select="[label]"></ng-content>
</button>
```

and story *button.story.ts*

```js
export default {
  title: 'Components/Button',
  component: ButtonComponent,
  decorators: [
    componentWrapperDecorator(ButtonComponent)
  ]
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<ButtonComponent> = (args: ButtonComponent) => ({
  moduleMetadata: {
  },
  template: `<app-button
                [color]="color"
                [type]="type"
                [size]="size"
                [disabled]="disabled"
                [outline]="outline"
                [block]="block"
                (onClick)="onClick()">
                <ng-container label>{{ labelContent }}</ng-container>
              </app-button>`,
  props: {...args},
});

export const Primary= Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {
  labelContent: 'Hello',
  color: 'primary',
  onClick: action('Button clicked')
};
```

I want to have `labelContent` dynamic so that the value can be changed from the control panel. But the values are not reflecting in the doc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I think all you need to do is to use `args.labelContent` instead of just `labelContent`.

Be advised: I am using Storybook 7 though, checkout my example:

```js
export const Primary: Story = {
  render: (args) => {
    return {
      props: args,
      template: `
      <vw-button>
        ${args.text}
      </vw-button>
    `,
    };
  },
  args: {
    text: 'Submit',
    variant: VwButtonVariant.PRIMARY,
    slot: VwButtonSlot.START,
    size: VwButtonSize.NORMAL,
    icon: undefined,
    disabled: false,
  },
};
```